# How to return more than one image from a function?

Tags: opencv

I feel that I'm doing the not efficient way of returning the image from the function.

If I use,

```
void processImg(IplImage* srcImg, IplImage* dstImg1, IplImage* dstImg2)
{
....processing image
cvCopy(..., dstImg1);
cvCopy(..., dstImg2);
}
```

For the above example, how can I return the two images back?

If I use IplImage*processImg(IplImage* srcImg, IplImage* dstImg1, IplImage* dstImg2), it only can return one image.

How can I return the images based on these two function?

Comment: The function as you listed it in the question takes pointers to dstImg1 and dstImg2, if you fill both of those (like you do with cvCopy) then they will retain their contents after the function returns and you have effectively "returned" both of them.  Could you be more specific as to what the problem is?

Comment: Am I doing the right way of returning the two images back from a function? I saw some post this isn't a good practice in programming.

Comment: C and C++ can't have more than 1 return argument, I would be very interested to see that post if it was talking about C or C++...

Comment: I forgot where I saw just now. The example I gave works actually. I just wondering if it is a good way. For instance if we want to return multiple value, preferable way of doing it by passing by reference etc...

Comment: I'm new to OpenCV so not sure if I can supply the best advice, but here are a couple of ideas that some to mind: 1. return an array or IplImage* typed vector containing the two images. 2. depending on how you need you need to use the images later either cvAdd them (although it's kind of a destructive process) or create a matrices with multiple channels (e.g. for 2 RGB images you'd create an output matrix with 6  channels (2xRGB), but this would mean making a matrix with the dimensions of the largest of the two images and wasting 'space' if the two images have different dimensions)...

Comment: ...or creating an array containing an index then 1D list of pixel values for each images, but it can get more convoluted than it should probably be

Comment: but as you mentioned, simply passing a reference is a good choice (feels more efficient/flexible)

Comment: hi George. I plan to return the 2 images back to the main function. Thereafter, I need the two images for another function separately. But how can I pass back if it is an image instead of using cvCopy?

Comment: You said about return an array or IplImage* typed vector. How  actually? Do you mind showing some example?

Comment: I dont see no problem with passing "return" arguments as pointers or reference to your function in your case. Plus, using "source" and "dest" names to your parameters gives the information to a user of your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing works. You are passing pointers to the two dst images. It means if you modify these images, you are actually modifying the original images.

If that is not what you are looking for and you really want to return two images, you can explore other data structures like list or linked list. You can put the two images in that structure and return the structure.

```
std::list<IplImage *> processImg(IplImage* srcImg)
{
    std::list<IplImage *> image_list;

    //....processing image

    //create two ipl images pointers
    IplImage *dstImg1, *dstImg2;

    //allocate memory for the ipl images

    //copy the data into images
    cvCopy(..., &dstImg1);
    cvCopy(..., &dstImg2);

    //add the images to list
    image_list.push_back(dstImg1);
    image_list.push_back(dstImg2);

    return image_list;
 }
```

Comment: "You are passing pointers to the two dst images. It means if you modify these images, you are actually modifying the original images."
I understand what you meant here but "you really want to return two images, you can explore other data structures like list or linked list. You can put the two images in that structure and return the structure." I don't really understand here. Could you explain more.

Comment: Besides Nick, there is no member function of "add" for std::list

Comment: Use push_back instead of add.

Comment: A data structure is a collection of similar data types. It could be anything like arrays, vectors, lists, maps, graphs etc. EAch of these have own set of properties. If you are not familiar with lists, you can put them in a vector and return the vector.